# React Native - Can't access Firebase Push Notification in foreground in Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement push notifications in React Native with Firebase console app by following this article:

*[React Native: Integrating Push Notifications using FCM](https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591)*

In Android, I'm able to receive notifications when the app is in background but unable to receive in foreground. Using this method to receive notifications:

```
async createNotificationListeners() {
  /*
   * Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
   * */
  this.notificationListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotification(notification => {
      console.log("fg", notification);
      const { title, body } = notification;
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

  /*
   * If app is in background, listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
   * */
  this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened(notificationOpen => {
      console.log("bg", notificationOpen);
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

  /*
   * If app is closed, check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
   * */
  const notificationOpen = await firebase
    .notifications()
    .getInitialNotification();
  if (notificationOpen) {
    console.log("bg", notificationOpen);
    const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
    this.showAlert(title, body);
  }
  /*
   * Triggered for data only payload in foreground
   * */
  this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage(message => {
    //process data message
    console.log("fg", JSON.stringify(message));
  });
}
```

Here, **`firebase.notifications().onNotification`** or **`firebase.messaging().onMessage()`** are not being triggered at all.

In other solutions, it's because from Android 8 you need to create a channel but I can't find any option to create channel while sending notification from FCM [notification composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abdul,

You need to make the notification channel using firebase on the device.

```
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android
  .Channel('default', 'Default Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
  .setDescription('The default notification channel.')

firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel)
```

This will create the channel, you can call it as many times as you want safely (according to the docs). Your onNotification listener looks fine, you just need to set the android channel on the notification that comes in.

```
  notification.android.setChannelId('default')
```

Comment: where should I create notification channel? `onNotification()` is still not triggered if I'm creating a channel in `componentDidMount()` of the base component of my app

Comment: That's the right place to put your listener. If the listener isn't firing at all I would start by double checking your setup for Messaging _and_ Notifications. Make sure your manifest file has a service that's handling the MESSAGE_EVENT.